# Finding the first triangle number with more than 500 divisors

Tags: java, factors

I am trying to solve the 12th Euler Problem in Java and I really can't seem to understand the problem here. The script is intended to output the first triangle number with more than 500 divisors, as detailed in the comment in the code. The correct answer is supposedly "76576500" whereas the answer my script outputs is "842161320" - a great magnitude off. Does anyone know where I am going wrong? All help is appreciated, thanks!

```
public class Script_012
{
/*
    The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be
    1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
    1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
    Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
    1: 1
    3: 1,3
    6: 1,2,3,6
    10: 1,2,5,10
    15: 1,3,5,15
    21: 1,3,7,21
    28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
    We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
    What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?
*/
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    boolean enough_factors = false;
    long num = 1;
    long runner = 1;
    int num_of_factors;
    int highest_factors = 0;
    while (!enough_factors)
    {
        num_of_factors = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < (int) Math.sqrt(num); i ++)
        {
            if ((num % i) == 0)
            {
                num_of_factors += 1;
            }
        }
        if (num_of_factors > 500)
        {
            enough_factors = true;
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        runner += 1;
        num += runner;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are only adding the factors less than or equal to the square root, but the question is talking about ALL factors, including ones greater than the square root.

Easy (but slow) solution:

Change `for (int i = 1; i < (int) Math.sqrt(num); i ++)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= num; i ++)`

Better solution:
Keep the same number of iterations of the for loop, but add 2 each time, and account for the square root only being one factor.
Code:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    boolean enough_factors = false;
    long num = 1;
    long runner = 1;
    int num_of_factors;
    int highest_factors = 0;
    while (!enough_factors)
    {
        num_of_factors = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < (int) Math.sqrt(num); i ++)
        {
            if ((num % i) == 0)
            {
                num_of_factors += 2;
            }
        }

        if(num % Math.sqrt(num) == 0) {
            num_of_factors++;
        }

        if (num_of_factors > 500)
        {
            enough_factors = true;
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        runner += 1;
        num += runner;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks man. I knew that it was going to be something to do with using Math.sqrt instead of looping through num, but it was taking way too long on my laptop.